# Tower of Hanoi sequence via eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations

> The following sequence comes from the [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi). $$ 1, 3, 7, 15, \dots $$ Find the $64$-th term using eigendecomposition.

---

By general pattern, I know that the answer is obviously $2^{64} -1$. However, I am asked to solve using eigendecomposition.

$$ T(n) = 2^n - 1 $$

Let $F_k$ be the terms of the sequence.

$$F_{k+1} = 2 F_k+1$$

In matrix form..

$$\begin{bmatrix} F_{k+1} \\F_k\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2&1 \\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} F_{k} \\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Please help me continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
\begin{align}\tag{1}
F_{k+1} &= 2F_k-1\\\tag{2}
F_k &= 2F_{k-1}-1
\end{align}
follows by substracting equation (2) from (1)
\begin{align}
F_{k+1}-F_k &= 2F_k-2F_{k-1}.
\end{align}
This leads to
\begin{align}
F_{k+1}&= 3F_k-2F_{k-1}.
\end{align}
We get
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}F_{k+1}\\F_{k}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3& -2\\ 1 &0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_{k}\\F_{k-1}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
You have to decompose $\begin{bmatrix}3& -2\\ 1 &0\end{bmatrix}$.